# What should I do with answers that try to solve the problem without answering the question?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

So there's a question that asks (basically): how can I change text like this?

OP (rightly, IMHO) accepted the upvoted regex answer. The original question title was something like "regex problems", after all.

But there's another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7179366/6083675) (with 0 score) that assumes that OP is using IE7 mode. You might wonder: what does that have to do with the question? I assume that IE7 mode may cause unquoted attributes. The text transformation the question asked for was quoting unquoted attribute values.

I know that it can often be helpful to redirect the way a question tries to solve its problem. But unquoted attributes are valid HTML, so IE7 mode isn't always the source of the problem.

Regardless, the answer doesn't explain how to do what it suggests. I think it should have been a comment, or at least an answer to a completely different question.

Please note that I have pushed edits for both the question and its accepted answer. I just want to ensure that the entirely of the thread is as good as possible, which is why I want to know about this.

The answer is bad, right? I'm not sure what flag I should use. Should I flag it at all, or do something else?

---

Note: all of this was posted a while ago, so people may not be active here anymore.

Comment: which flag would you use? I mean, you can downvote it if you think it's not good. But I don't see a flag that should stick on that answer

Comment: I assume that OP is joking. Back in the days fun was allowed on main. Now we hat fun.

Comment: It's nearly 5 years old. Who cares? Neither answer seems to meet the not-useful criteria to me, except that IE7 is now obsolete.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I do, at least. Quality is important no matter how old the post is.

Comment: Side note: As OP of the answer ...In general I would appreciate comment or downvote to notify me of questionable content (in addition/instead of flagging). I don't think my answer is of good quality as it missing reasoning why suggestion is related (and includes unrelated snarky comment), so I'll delete it in couple days (to let <10K META visitors to see it).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't know you were still active! Just to be clear, I think if you put some more details into the answer, it would be a good answer--for another question.

Answer (score 5):

It certainly wouldn't merit flagging, or deletion.

As to whether or not such an answer is helpful is going to vary based on context, and the professional opinion of the reader.  You're going to need to make a judgement call about how likely it is that this answer has accurately predicted the underlying problem, how effective that solution is for that problem as compared to the approach the OP actually asked for a solution for, etc.

You, as a voter, may decide that the answer isn't helpful as a result of not answering the question asked, and downvote it as a result.  You might also decide that it most likely does accurately predict the real problem, and provide a solution that's much better for solving that problem than what the question asks about, making that answer quite helpful, meriting an upvote.

All of that said, this is a problem that is best avoided (both by the question author, and the answerer).  This is why, when asking your question, it's best to include relevant context for your question.  If you explain that you're looking for a way to Foo the Bar, and you think that the best way to do that is to Baz the Bar, and you're running into a given error in doing so, then a correct answer can *either* explain how to resolve the problem Bazzing the bar or simply explain that Bazing the Bar isn't the best way to Foo the Bar.  Such a question stays sufficiently specific, while still allowing for the most helpful answers.

Additionally, an answerer can both answer the literal question asked, and then also explain what they think the root cause is, and what they feel is the better approach for solving that problem.  This is fine, as long as answering the actual question wouldn't be harmful; sometime answer the question *would* be harmful and it's important to *not* provide a solution to the question asked.  If you *do* feel that it would be harmful to provide a solution to the question asked, it's almost certainly worthwhile to at least *explain why you're not answering the literal question asked*.

In many cases, when you see such an answer to a question you might even consider trying to have the question and/or answer edited so that they do some of the things that I've mentioned.  If you can have the author edit in the underlying problem then answerers don't need to guess at what it is, if an answerer feels that answering the literal question would be harmful help them to *edit in an explanation* of why that would be bad, etc.

Comment: The q is old, so people may no longer be active.

Comment: @Laurel For that one example, perhaps, in which case you wouldn't apply the advice of the last paragraph to that example.

Comment: Also, I think the question was specific enough: it asked for a regex to do x. The answer did not mention anything about regexes. It certainly did not advise against regexes for doing x.

Comment: @Laurel I never said that that question *wasn't* specific enough.  If anything my point was that when the best answer to a question is to tell them that they're using the wrong approach then it's a sign that the question is *too* specific.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to consider the OP to be the prototypical user of your answer.  In essence, future visitors who will make use of your answer, are likely people facing the same or a similar scenario that the OP is facing.

With that in mind, I would consider an answer that doesn't answer the literal question, but solves the OP's problem superior to an answer that answers the literal question, but does not solve the OP's problem.

Stack Overflow is not a trivia game.  It's for helping people.  Technically correct answers, and answers to the literal question aren't good enough unless they're useful answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is not useful for the majority of cases. I had to search for a while, but the answer relates to [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231770/innerhtml-removes-attribute-quotes-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: @Laurel then downvote it.